# Types and software to backup

Tags: networking, backup

Which the best software to use for make backup complete of my data? I prefer the program if run in the terminal and allow backup through network, internal networking.

I don't know must about backup and their types. Which articles or documents do you advise to read?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Duplicity` is a good option, you can find the website [here](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/). There is also a graphical front-end that ties into the Backup settings in Ubuntu called Déjà Dup.

More info can be found at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/2598/175503) Ask Ubuntu answer.